# Filtering DatagridView with DateTimePicker and TextBoxes

Tags: c#

I have a dataGridView and have logs inside it. I wanted to filter by time and number and name. There is no problem in working separately. When the textbox and datetimepicker are filtered together, I get the error that the variable of type bindingsource unable to be cast to dataview. how do i solve this problem?

I'm not printing the lines between two dates, I'm directly filtering the date written in the flight_date column. gridFilter = datagridview

```
 private void timeFilter_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(inputpath))
            {
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)gridFilter.DataSource;
                DataView dv = new DataView();
                dv = dt.DefaultView;
                dv.RowFilter = "Flight_Date >= '" + timeFilter.Value.Date + "' and  Flight_Date <= '" +
                timeFilter.Value.Date + "'";
            }
        }
        catch(System.InvalidCastException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    private void txt_filterNum_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists(inputpath))
        {
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = gridFilter.DataSource;
            bs.Filter = gridFilter.Columns[indexRoleNum].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + Convert.ToString(txt_filterNum.Text) + "%'";
            gridFilter.DataSource = bs;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code makes little sense as it is. Add a `BindingSource` to your form in the designer. Populate your `DataTable`, bind that to the `BindingSource` and bind that to the grid. When you want to filter, you don't need to create any new objects. Just set the `Filter` of the existing `BindingSource`. If you want to match the date and the name then you'll need to `AND` those conditions in the filter expression. You should write a single method that creates the filter and call it from both the event handlers.

Comment: @John using bindingsource is not crucial. Do you have any clean idea?

Comment: It's also worth noting that it is a bad idea to filter on a `TextChanged` event. If you do so, the data will be filtered multiple times when the user types multiple characters, making the process inefficient. It is better to use a `Timer` with a small `Interval`, e.g. 500 ms, and do the filtering on the `Tick` event. You can then start/restart the `Timer` on the `TextChanged` event. That way, the user can type multiple characters and only filter when they stop typing, but without having to wait too long.

Comment: *"Do you have any clean idea?"*. I already told you what to do.

Comment: @John I added a BindingSource and in my load function where datatable is created, assigned bindingsource's datasource as dt also gridview's. Then, in the textChanged functions, I just wrote bindingsource1.Filter = ......... That's okay, right? It looks working. And creating that method, can you write the basic structure ?

Comment: I will post an answer on the assumption that you have a `DataTable` correctly bound to the grid via a `BindingSource` but you should update your question to that affect, so that my answer actually addresses the question you have asked.

Comment: Before I add an answer, I should point out that your date filter doesn't make sense. You only have one `DateTimePicker` but you're using it for both the start and end of the range. As it stands, you will only include records where `Flight_Date` is an exact match to the date in your control. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @John Yes. Only Exact match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the bind has been done correctly, i.e. a `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` to the grid, you could filter the data like this:

```cs
private void timeFilter_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetFilter();
}

private void txt_filterNum_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetFilter();
}

private void SetFilter()
{
    myBindingSource.Filter = $"Flight_Date = #{timeFilter.Value:M/dd/yyyy}# AND {gridFilter.Columns[indexRoleNum].HeaderText} LIKE '%{txt_filterNum.Text}%'";
}
```

As I suggested in the comments, it may provide a better experience if you implement a delay between the text changing and the filtering being done:

```cs
private void timeFilter_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetFilter();
}

private void txt_filterNum_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    filterTimer.Stop();
    filterTimer.Start();
}

private void filterTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    filterTimer.Stop();
    SetFilter();
}

private void SetFilter()
{
    myBindingSource.Filter = $"Flight_Date = #{timeFilter.Value:M/dd/yyyy}# AND {gridFilter.Columns[indexRoleNum].HeaderText} LIKE '%{txt_filterNum.Text}%'";
}
```

Comment: Simulator simRead = new Simulator(inputpath);
            DataTable dt = simRead.MakeDataTable();
            bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;
            gridFilter.DataSource = bindingSource1;    Is it true for defining the bindingsource?

Comment: also i have a problem about deselecting the datetimepicker